# how to write a toString for two objects pointing to each other

Tags: java

```
class A {
    String one;
    String two;
    B bRef;
    Collection<B> bCollRef;

    A(String one, String two)
    {
        this.one = one;
        this.two = two;
    }

    //setters for bRef and bCollRef;
}

class B {
    String three;
    A a;

    B(String three)
    {
        this.three = three;
    }

    //setter for a
}

A a1 = new A(...);
A a2 = new A(...);
a1.setbRef(new B(str,a2));
a2.setbCollRef(new B(str,a1));
```

a2 is like child for a1, and a1 is parent for a2. Whats the best way to write the toString method for these classes and avoid stackoverflow error.

Comment: How would you like the `toString` to look?  Figure that out first, then implement it.

Comment: Want to have all the attributes in both the classes

Comment: You could also create subclass C that inherits from B except that it has an object of type A, whereas B does not.  Meanwhile class A has an object of type B.

Comment: I am just wondering, do you use classes like this: B tmp; new A(tmp = new B()); tmp.setA(new A(null));

Comment: Interesting question. But I think the underlying design is questionable...

Comment: @keuleJ more than questionable, the design is almost like a really bad circular linked list, except instead of just the `A` nodes linked to each other he's using that `B` object in the middle which will probably cause a ton of GC issues, but hey, his funeral, question's answered.

Comment: This question should be closed for either not giving enough information (what the return value for `toString` should look like) or for being too broad ("what is the best way to write the toString method..." seems more opinion-based, ignoring the StackOverflow error which is almost certainly mentioned because the OP didn't want to show what he/she tried before).

Answer (score 1):

This would work, assuming you have a public accessor for your `A` reference in `B`

```
class A {
    String one;
    String two;
    B bRef;
    Collection<B> bCollRef;

    A(String one, String two)
    {
        this.one = one;
        this.two = two;
    }

    //setters for bRef and bCollRef;

    @Override
    public void toString(){

        if(bRef.geta() == this)
            //you have a circular reference, dont step into it(don't call the next toString() method) and you won't stackoverflow here
        else
            //no circular reference, no problems here, tostring it as you will

    }
}
```

Now, how you write your `toString()` method is up to how you want your object to be converted into a string... this simple if statement will protect you from the circular reference. If you have any more references that might complicate things, I suggest you take a step back and rethink how you are doing things, your objects shouldn't need to see every single other object.

IF YOU DID have a higher-order circular reference situation and had references `b1` and `b2` like `a1 -> b1 -> a2 -> b2 -> a1` you would need to write code like this.. in practice you will want to be very careful about null references, though:

```
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        //do tostring stuff on current object
        A nextA = bRef.geta(); 
        //do tostring stuff on next stuff

        while(nextA != this){
             nextA = nextA.getbRef.getA();
             //unravel the references until you come around full-circle
        }

    }
```

Comment: this will not solve problem if a1 references b1, b1 references a2, a2 references b2 and b2 references a1

Comment: @hoaz noted, but the way OP laid things out, there are no `b1` or `b2` references, the objects are created but just set into a1 and a2... what you have here is also a nightmare for garbage collection, he would need methods specifically tailored to unwinding his circular references.

Answer (score 0):

a2 may be "like a child for a1", but it is also like a parent for a1.  You have a cycle in your data structures.  You could do a lot of things, depending on what you want things to look like; the first that came to my mind was for toString to test the local reference of its other object to see if it contained a reference to itself, and handle things accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Could be done on many ways, depending what do you need.

One solution could be to make toString() method to accept parameter, like this:

```
//in class A
@Override
String toString(){
    return toString(true);
}

/**
@Param subclass Should subclass info be included 
*/
String toString(boolean subclass){
    String text = /* details from current class */;
    if (subclass && bRef != null)
        text += bRef.toString(false);
    return text;
}
```

Same can be applied for class `B`, just replace `bRef` with `a`

And when you need `String` from some object, just call `toString()` (without arguments)

---

However, if you have cases where you have references like this for example: `a1 -> b1`; `b1 -> a2`; `a2 -> b2`; `b2 -> a1`

Then this approach would be better:

```
//in class A
@Override
String toString(){
    return toString(new Stack<Object>());
}

/**
@Param stack Holds all objects that have been called
*/
String toString(Stack stack){
    String text = /* details from current class */;
    if (bRef != null && stack != null && stack.search(bRef) == -1)
    {
        stack.push(bRef);
        text += bRef.toString(stack);
    }
    return text;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, will correct immediately. And thanks for informing me :)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you want the `toString` to look like for `A` and `B`, but I'll just make a guess.

```
class A {
    private String getStringRepresentation() {
        return one + " | " + two;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return bRef.toString();
    }
}

class B {
    public String toString() {
        return three + "[" + aRef.getStringRepresentation() + "]"
    }
}
```

Comment: not to be harsh, but your answer completely misses the target as far as this question goes. The example is not easily understandable, incorrect(there is no purpose to returning the string representations of the references) and does not solve the stackoverflow. and certainly does not resolve higher-order circular references.

Comment: I had a general sense that the OP was having issues with the `toString` of both classes calling each other.  Beyond that, there's not much else to go by as far as I know.  But thanks for the feedback.